# phpMyAdmin not working on my ubuntu system, using xampp

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvBnP.png)
Facing this error when i try and open localhost/phpmyadmin.

My last couple error logs:

```
2024-03-17 10:08:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 1764435; transaction id 2369
2024-03-17 10:08:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-03-17 10:08:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240317 10:08:31
2024-03-17 10:08:31 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-03-17 10:08:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-03-17 10:08:31 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in use
2024-03-17 10:08:31 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2024-03-17 10:08:31 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2024-03-17 10:08:32 2562807 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mariyas-laptop.pid ended
```

Exhausted gpt4 for solutions, tried to change some configurations between local host and other servers on my config.inc.php file. I also killed the background SQL service running on the port. Reinstalled xampp twice, first time w/an Apache error and now with this.

Comment: Look at the first 2 `[ERROR]` messages ... is there already have a running instance of MySQL on the system?